# PHP contact form font color is stuck to black

Tags: php, forms, fonts, colors

No matter what i try strangely enough my form and thank you page both php files one with embed font coloring and one with an external style sheet refuse to change font color from black.

thank you php file:
http://www.richiesportfolio.com/contact/thank-you.php

contact form php file:
http://www.richiesportfolio.com/contact/contactform.php

Everything else works purfectly but changing the contact forms font color

contactform.php

`

```
<?PHP

require_once("./include/fgcontactform.php");

$formproc = new FGContactForm();


if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
{
   if($formproc->ProcessForm())
   {
        $formproc->RedirectToURL("thank-you.php");
   }
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US">
<head>
      <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
      <title>Contact us</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.richiesportfolio.com/contact/contact.css" />
      <script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/gen_validatorv31.js'></script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Form Code Start -->
<form id='contactus' action='<?php echo $formproc->GetSelfScript(); ?>' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
<fieldset >
<legend>Contact Me</legend>

<input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>
<input type='hidden' name='<?php echo $formproc->GetFormIDInputName(); ?>' value='<?php echo $formproc->GetFormIDInputValue(); ?>'/>
<input type='text'  class='spmhidip' name='<?php echo $formproc->GetSpamTrapInputName(); ?>' />

<div class='short_explanation'>* required fields</div>

<div><span class='error'><?php echo $formproc->GetErrorMessage(); ?></span></div>
<div class='container'>
    <label for='name' >Your Full Name*: </label><br/>
    <input type='text' name='name' id='name' value='<?php echo $formproc->SafeDisplay('name') ?>' maxlength="50" /><br/>
    <span id='contactus_name_errorloc' class='error'></span>
</div>
<div class='container'>
    <label for='email' >Email Address*:</label><br/>
    <input type='text' name='email' id='email' value='<?php echo $formproc->SafeDisplay('email') ?>' maxlength="50" /><br/>
    <span id='contactus_email_errorloc' class='error'></span>
</div>

<div class='container'>
    <label for='message' >Message:</label><br/>
    <span id='contactus_message_errorloc' class='error'></span>
    <textarea rows="10" cols="50" name='message' id='message'><?php echo $formproc->SafeDisplay('message') ?></textarea>
</div>


<div class='container'>
    <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Submit' />
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>
<!-- client-side Form Validations:
Uses the excellent form validation script from JavaScript-coder.com-->

<script type='text/javascript'>
// <![CDATA[

    var frmvalidator  = new Validator("contactus");
    frmvalidator.EnableOnPageErrorDisplay();
    frmvalidator.EnableMsgsTogether();
    frmvalidator.addValidation("name","req","Please provide your name");

    frmvalidator.addValidation("email","req","Please provide your email address");

    frmvalidator.addValidation("email","email","Please provide a valid email address");

    frmvalidator.addValidation("message","maxlen=2048","The message is too long!(more than 2KB!)");

// ]]>
</script>

</body>
</html>`
```

contact.css

```
body,table,tr,td,a,p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,input,h3 a,h4 a,h5 ul, li, ul, a  {
   color:#FFF;
}

#contactus fieldset {
   width:320px;
   padding:20px;
   border:20px;
   -moz-border-radius: 10px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
   -khtml-border-radius: 10px; border-radius: 10px;
}

#contactus legend, h2 {
   font-family : Arial, sans-serif;
   font-size:1.3em;
   font-weight:bold;
   color:#FFF;
}

#contactus label {
   font-family : Arial, sans-serif;
   font-size:0.8em;
   font-weight: bold;
   color:#FFF;
}

#contactus input[type="text"],textarea {
   font-family : Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;   font-size: 0.8em;  
   line-height:140%;
   color : #000;   
   padding : 3px;
   border : 1px solid;
   #999;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
   border-radius: 5px; 
}

#contactus input[type="text"] {
   height:18px;
   width:220px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
   border-radius: 5px;
}

#contactus #scaptcha {
   width:60px;
   height:18px;
}

#contactus input[type="submit"] {
   width:100px;
   height:30px;   
   padding-left:0px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 5px;   -moz-border-radius: 5px;    border-radius: 5px;    }

#contactus textarea {
   height:120px;
   width:310px;
   -webkit-border-radius:8px;
   -moz-border-radius: 8px;   
   border-radius: 8px;
}

#contactus input[type="text"]:focus,textarea:focus {
   color : #009;
   border : 1px solid #990000;
   background-color : #ffff99;
   font-weight:bold;
}

#contactus .container {
   margin-top:8px;
   margin-bottom:10px;
   color:#FFF;
}

#contactus .error {
   font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;    
   font-size: 0.7em;    color: #900;   
   background-color : #111;
}

#contactus fieldset#antispam {
   padding:2px;
   border-top:1px solid #EEE;
   border-left:0;
   border-right:0;
   border-bottom:0;   
   width:350px; }

#contactus fieldset#antispam legend {
   font-family : Arial, sans-serif;   
   font-size: 0.8em;
   font-weight:bold;
   color:#FFF;
}

#contactus .short_explanation {
   font-family : Arial, sans-serif;   
   font-size: 0.6em;
   color:#FFF;
}

/* spam_trap: This input is hidden. This is here to trick the spam bots*/
#contactus .spmhidip {
   display:none;
   width:10px;   
   height:3px;
}
#fg_crdiv {
   font-family : Arial, sans-serif;
   font-size: 0.3em;   
   opacity: .2;
   -moz-opacity: .2;   
   filter: alpha(opacity=20);
}
#fg_crdiv p {
   display:none;
}
```

Comment: Here is the address to my contact form:
http://www.richiesportfolio.com/contact.html

Comment: Can you please post the code?

Comment: I edited your post to make the css code readable, if you don't mind. I'd suggest that next time, you post your code then click the 'code' button (**`{}`**) next time ;)

Comment: also, you forgot a few `;`'s here and there. This screws up your code.

Comment: try validating your css in the W3C tool : http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input

Answer (score 4):

On the thank you page, you're using `font:#fff;` in the `style` attribute. Change it to `color: #fff;`.

The labels in the contact page don't specify a color so it's inherited from the closest parent that specified a color. Add a style for labels that specify `color: #fff`.

Comment: @Richard Hayward - Your thank you page still has `font:#fff` and you still don't have any `color` style on your labels for the contact us page. Where did you make the change?

Comment: Locally forgot to upload it. Its also not applying to the form when I set the contactform.php contact.css to body color white